# Copy image to server directory from iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ios

Based on a tutorial I've build an iOS app that uploads images from the device to an web server directory. It worked fine in my localhost, but when I uploaded the files to the server and tested the file weren't copied to the directory I specified! So I suppose in Xcode everything working correctly, the PHP file I using to upload to my server is bellow:

```
<?php 

$connect = mysql_connect("xxxxxxxxx","xxxx","xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
$connectDB = mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxx");

$insertData = "INSERT INTO feras (nome,vulgo,imagelink) VALUES ('".$_GET['feraname']."','".$_GET['feravulgo']."','http://localhost:8888/ImageUpIPhone/uploads/".$_GET['imagelink'].".jpg')";
$sendData = mysql_query($insertData);

//$file_name = substr ( md5(uniqid(rand(),1)), 5, 15); 
$file_name = $_GET['imagelink'];

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$newname = $file_name . $file;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newname;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $imagepath =  "http://example.com/uploads/{$newname}";
}
print $imagepath;
?>
```

So, how can I fix that? In my localhost it worked and in the server it doesn't, I can only figure that's about the directory! I using a free host (ueuo.com).

Comment: Is the new upload putting an entry in the database? What are the user permissions on your main `htdocs` dir and what are the permissions on your `upload` dir?

Comment: how big is the file your uploading? pretty sure a raw 5MP image is over 2mb & some hosts allow only 2mb post size, if its over you have no error logging or reporting in your php so it will just fail..

Comment: The file might have about 1M and 2M.Can you be more specific about those permissions,i still learning.

Comment: Even if the picture have low size the code doesn't work.I trying to upload an image that i took from internet,it has 256kb!